# Ajax Request to included JSON - readystate 4, status 0

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am performing an Ajax GET request on a JSON file included in my website. So the JSON file is included in a separate sheet. The readystate of the request is "4" while the status is "0". So the request has been sent, but the responsetext is empty.

I have validated the JSON data. 
The javascript file returns data where it should on HTML5 page. 
Error handling gives readystate "4" and status "0".

This is the code of the javascript file, JSON data is correct and tested.. HTML5 connection also functions as it should, tested.. The javascript file inserts data on the correct element in HTML..

Can anyone spot the error? Thanks everyone!

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();                 //create Request Object

xhr.onload = function(){                        //when the Request is loaded, parse it in a responsetext 

if(xhr.status === 200){

    var responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    var newContent ='';

    for (var i=0; i<responseObject.events.length; i++){

        newContent += responseObject.events[i].color;

        newContent += responseObject.events[i].value;

    }

    document.getElementById("jsonreturn_option").innerHTML = newContent;
}

else{

    document.getElementById("jsonreturn_option").innerHTML = xhr.readyState + "    " + xhr.status  ;

    //readystate is 4, which means that the request has been sent.. 
    //request status is 0, which means that the responsetext is empty.. 
}
};

xhr.open('GET','json/options_form.json',true);
xhr.send(null);                                         //no additional data to be sent
```

The JSON Data File

```
{
"events":[

{  "color": "red", "value": "#f00"},
{  "color": "green", "value": "#0f0"},
{  "color": "blue", "value": "#00f"},
{  "color": "cyan", "value": "#0ff"}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need create javaweb project and then setup a tomcat server
2. put all files to javaweb project and then startup tomcat server
3. open browser type like :  http://localhost:8080/javaweb/test.html

because `xhr.open('GET','json/options_form.json',true);` can not request local file,   must request server file

Comment: Thank you verejava, this has helped me a lot! I looked a bit further on the web, and found that there is another way to do it, through the use of FileReader(). This Object lets applications read locally stored files. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 0):

Try `xhr.onreadystatechange` instead of `xhr.onload`and also move `xhr.open` and `xhr.send` to top of `xhr.onload`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I still have the same logs, so readystate 4 and a problem at status 0, empty responsetext..